# hebrew name for someone who was never given one

Tags: names

There is a person whose parents never gave a Hebrew name. What should be done in terms of giving that person a new name now? Can anyone give the name? Can the person choose a name? Is there a special ceremony or bracha to say when giving the name?

Comment: What's wrong with their current name?

Comment: @DoubleAA what are you saying, I'm just asking how to give someone a hebrew name, Im not debating whether or not one should, this discussion is completely irrelevant

Comment: You asked "What should be done in terms of giving that person a new name now?” Unless you have something else to present about what's wrong with the current name (besides its etymology?), the answer would seem to be nothing. I'm not saying you _couldn't_ if you still wanted to.

Comment: Yaakov5777 If the nonjewish name is a name s/he was given by their parents in memory of their parents, then he shouldn't change it to a 'Jewish' name. At least according to Rabbi Moshe Feinstein who learned it from all the Amoraim who had decidedly non Jewish names like Rav Papa had.

Comment: @user and if the person was never given any kind of hey